# Camp Des Chaumes, France WWII

Tags: military-records, world-war-2, france, imprisonment

My father was assigned to Camp Des Chaumes during WWII.  I have a painting of the camp made by a prisoner, Johann Thomsen, dated 1946.  I am trying to find out any information about the camp and about him.

Comment: The AJPN website has a page with [details of the camp](http://www.ajpn.org/internement-Camp-des-Chaumes-150.html) including a basic chronology.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas on how to track down the artist, Johann Thomsen?